# wp_redirect not working on plugin

Tags: plugins, wp-redirect

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Héroes y Pasta
*/
    include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
    function iniciatodo() {
        if(is_user_logged_in()) {
?>
            <p>Hola tio</p>
<?php
        } else {
            wp_redirect( "http://gexy.es.cx/login/" );
            exit();
        }
    }
    add_shortcode("inicia_todo", "iniciatodo");
?>
```

So I'm making a pluging that has to work different if the user is logged in or not, but when the user is not logged it should redirect to the login page. What is wrong with the code or what does it lacks?

Thank you in advance

Comment: maybe that when the shortcode is send, headers are already send and then "wp_redirect" is not able to work. Another solution is to test in the action `wp_loaded` if you are at this page, do the redirection.

Comment: @mmm stop leaving answers as comments

Comment: why is it a shortcode?

Comment: Also, why is `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php being included`? It should be unnecessary and can cause security issues loading it on the frontend

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider a Javascript solution by adding a portion of code that will redirect people to the page if not loggued in :

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Héroes y Pasta
*/
    include_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php');
    function iniciatodo() {
        if(is_user_logged_in()) {
?>
            <p>Hola tio</p>
<?php
        } else { ?>
            <script>window.location.href = 'http://gexy.es.cx/login/';</script>
       <?php }
    }
    add_shortcode("inicia_todo", "iniciatodo");
```